# Area between $ 2 y = 4 \sqrt{x}$, $y = 4$, and $2 y + 4 x = 8 $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, curves

Sketch the region enclosed by the curves given below. Then find the area of the region.

$ 2 y = 4 \sqrt{x}$, $y = 4$, and $2 y + 4 x = 8 $

Attempt at solution:

I guess I'm supposed to divide the areas into several parts, and then sum up the areas of those parts.

[Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=area%20between%20curves%202y%20%3D%204sqrt%28x%29%20and%20y%3D4%20and%202y%2B4x%20%3D8) shows the sketched area... and I don't think those are the correct sketched areas, because the answer 14 isn't a correct answer.

So can someone tell me which sketched areas am I even looking at?

Comment: I would interpret the question as asking for the area of the roughly triangular region on top (not shaded).

Comment: what should be the correct answer? If you know 14 is wrong

Comment: Agreed with @AndréNicolas . Like between $x=0$ and $x=1$ you have $-2x+4 \le y \le 4$ and between $x=1$ and $x=4$ you have $2 \sqrt{x} \le y \le 4$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplify your boundary equations:

$$y = 2 \sqrt{x}$$
$$y = 4$$
$$y = -2x +4$$

Sketch the area. You ought to try hand-sketching it to verify.

[image: bounded area]

Split into two double integrals.

$$Area = \int_{x=0}^1\int_{y=lower curve}^{higher curve} dydx+ \int_{x=1}^4\int_{y=lower curve}^{higher curve}dydx$$.

**UPDATE/EDIT**: You ought to have solved it by now. For reference, here's the full integration and solution.

$$= \int_{x=0}^1\int_{y=-2x+4}^{4} dydx+ \int_{x=1}^4\int_{y=2\sqrt{x}}^{4}dydx$$

$$= \int_{x=0}^1 4 - (-2x+4) dx+ \int_{x=1}^4 4- 2\sqrt{x}\ dx$$

$$= 2\int_{x=0}^1 x\ dx+ \int_{x=1}^4 4- 2\sqrt{x}\ dx$$

$$= x^2 \bigg|_0^1 + 4x \bigg|_1^4 - \frac{4}{3}x^{\frac{3}{2}} \bigg|_1^4 $$

$$= 11/3 $$

Comment: How did you do that pretty picture?

Comment: Copied WA's pic with print screen key. Used MS Paint to fill the necessary areas :)

Answer (score 3):

For the region where $x$ goes from $x=0$ to $x=1$ $y$ goes from $4-2x$ to $4$.

For the region where $x$ goes from $x=1$ to $x=4$ $y$ goes from $2\sqrt{x}$ to $4$.

Thus, the area is given by

$$\text{Area} =\int_0^1 \int_{4-2x}^4 dydx+\int_1^4 \int_{2\sqrt x}^4 dydx$$

Can you finish?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%284-%28-2x%2B4%29%2Cx%3D0..1%29%2Bintegrate%284-2+sqrt%28x%29%2Cx%3D1..4%29 I don't think W.A. has it correct.

Comment: You are right with respect to that reference; it is incorrect.  The OP had another reference that plotted the curves.

Comment: Yeah you right too I guess then. Wolfram had the correct sketching of the curves. Just a different interpretation of what was meant by area between the curves given.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the region:

[image]

You can perform the integration in two parts, where the limits are determined by the values of $x$ where the appropriate two equations have the same value.  I'll leave the details of that exercise to you but the result is ${11 \over 3}$.

Since you asked, here's the *Mathematica* code:

```
Plot[{4, 2 Sqrt[x], If[0 < x < 1, 4, Null], If[1 < x < 4, 4, Null], 
  4 - 2 x}, {x, -1, 5},
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Red, Red, Orange},
 Filling -> {
   {3 -> {{5}, {None, Green}}}, 
   {4 -> {{2}, {None, Blue}}}
   }]
```